# Twitter API - Missing } after property list

Tags: jquery, api, twitter

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({url:'https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424829.json?callback=?', dataType:'json',   
  success:function(data)
  {
    console.dir(data);   
  } } );
});
```

**example**
http://jsfiddle.net/W8AAZ/

i get the error `missing } after property list` .. but why?

Comment: the URL gives me an error, let me check later :)

Comment: This is an error on twitter's side, they're looking into it: http://twitter.com/#!/episod/statuses/114105510772486144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424829.json?callback=i_appear_multiple_times

Looks like twitters api is broken. :-/